# Get error "No serializer found for class org.json.JSONArray and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer"

Tags: java, json

I am using an method as :

```
 public JSONObject createRequest(String Id,String hidden)
 {  
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();      
    obj.put(ConfigParser.getProperty("hide_param1"), Id);
    obj.put(ConfigParser.getProperty("hide_param2"), hidden);

    JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();
    myArray.put(obj);

    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    mainObj.put("Visibility", myArray);

    System.out.println(mainObj);
  return mainObj;
 }
```

this method I am callin as

```
Response req = ApiTestUtils.reponseFromPutRequestWithCookies(path,createRequest(getAlertID,"true"),Cookies);
```

so in createRequest method I am getting this error.Please suggest what I did wrong in this.

Error Stack:
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONArray and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.json.simple.JSONObject["Visibility"])

Comment: Please add the library you are using in the question and add the error stacktrace too

Comment: I added the stack trace

Comment: Find a solution to this issue?